# Adding pictures to virtuemart product

Tags: virtuemart, images

All I want to do is upload pictures to my virtuemart products from Imgur rather than my computer because I can only use a total of 2 gigabytes for the whole site. I am just learning to do any website building. Please help

Answer (score 1):

**Add external hosted images to product:**

products -> product images -> "used url" & "used thumb url"

For importing images from Imgur to your Virtuemart webspace you need to write an extension which utilize the Imgur api. (I did this already for Dropbox.)

***But, I would recommend to resize your images to max 800x800px and compress them with 60 to 80% quality. Even you 2GB webspace should be big enough for that. (1000 images * 100kb / 1024 ~ 97MB)***